# How to run a service in background on Android 10? Rooted device

Tags: android, android-service, root, background-process, android-10.0

I have a rooted Android 10 and a service. It records the mic and accesses GPS coordinates.
I'm trying to launch and run it in background, with no additional notifications in the Notification tray. And without any activity, icon, anything visual form.

I'll use ADB to launch it.

I've found out that there's no way anymore to run it in background initially - it has to be run in foreground first.  But it then can be shifted to background and continue there with **no notifications at all**.

Is this correct?

If so, is it done by 2 consequetive calls:

```
val serviceAdditionaPermissions = FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_LOCATION or FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MICROPHONE

startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, createNotification(), serviceAdditionaPermissions)
stopForeground(AccessibilityService.STOP_FOREGROUND_DETACH)
```

And it'll continue in background? With no notifications.

It'll be ok for me to run it first, for 1 minute, in foreground, as long as it then gets shifted into background.

Also, can root be leveraged here to overcome these restrictions?

Comment: If its in the background, it will be killed after 2 minutes of being backgrounded for resources.  You'd need a custom build of Android to get around that.

Comment: @GabeSechan where does it say so - 2 minutes? How do all other priviligied services run continiously then?

Comment: 2 minutes is pretty well known, although the documents technically say "several minutes", which gives them room to fiddle with it or tweak it per device.  https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background  "When an app goes into the background, it has a window of several minutes in which it is still allowed to create and use services. At the end of that window, the app is considered to be idle. At this time, the system stops the app's background services, "

Comment: And other services either are Linux based services which don't have to follow those rules, or they don't work as services (a lot of things people seem to think are services are push message listeners or work manager tasks)